# Copying vector of structures

Tags: rust, closures

I am implementing a Rust application where the vector of structures are to be passed into a closure.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct AttackInfo {
    ppid: usize,
    pname: &'static str,
    cpu: f32,
}

type AList = Vec<AttackInfo>;

fn Task() {
    let mut list: AList = AList::new();

    // ...
    // I fill up the list with many items
    // ...

    output.put(|msg| *msg = Some(Message::Value(list)));
}
```

`output.put` is a function that takes a closure, this is defined by the library.

I am unable to send the value of list because of the error for the `list` variable:

```
cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

The closure will be executed multiple times until all the values in the list are emptied. How can I send the list data without losing the scope of the variable?

Comment: *The closure will be executed multiple times till all the values in the list are emptied. How can I send the list data without loosing the scope of the variable.* => what do you mean? Looking at the code as written I would expect `list` to be consumed *once* completely (in one shot).

Comment: I meant that the function `put` will read out all the data in the vector. Of course the function takes it at one shot.

Comment: Naming functions with capital letters is not idiomatic Rust. Functions and variables use `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `Message::Value(list)`, you have consumed `list` by passing it to `Value`. `FnMut` closures *may* be executed multiple times so the compiler must assume that it will be called multiple times. Since your closure is attempting to move `list`, the compiler complains because you are not allowed to move a value out of a location multiple times.

Depending on what `output.put()` is trying to do there might be several solutions:

- If the closure will only be called once, then you should change the type of the closure argument to `FnOnce`. This will allow you to move `list` as you are trying to do.
- If the closure may be called multiple times, you will need to take a reference to `list` and then clone it:

  ```
  fn Task() {
      let mut list: AList = AList::new();

      // ...
      // I fill up the list with many items
      // ...

      output.put(|msg| *msg = Some(Message::Value((&list).clone())));
  }
  ```

Comment: A simple reference might do instead of an `Rc`, wouldn't it?.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs, a simple reference was perfect.